# Add permissions to unit tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-permissions

I followed this tutorial to create a Unit Test for my Android app in Android Studio: http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/

The problem I have is that in my unit tests I need to access the Internet, so I require Internet permission on an AndroidManifest.xml file. Currently, I get "Connection refused (EACCES)" when I try to hit the Internet from my tests.

How do I do that? I tried adding the manifest file inside my com.example.app.tests folder, but it is not working. It doesn't take into account the manifest file of the Android library I want to test, either.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are using internet connection in test. They are not unit test. Try to mock connection so you will test only part of your code